# Appendix from letter to roman numeral

Tags: sectioning, numbering, appendices

How can I change the standard latex Appendix heading from "Appendix A" to "Appendix I" using roman numerals?

Comment: Try \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

Comment: I'm inputting my appendix from a separate file and it doesn't like the \Roman command

Comment: @Helen: In this case, how about adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: If the OP uses an article class, there are only sections, even in the `appendix`, so `\renewcommand{thesection}{\Roman{section}}` would be the solution. This could be the reason, why `\Roman` fails, since the counter chapter is unknown, not the command `\Roman` itself

Comment: BTW, you should put this after \appendix and before the next \chapter, or \section.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Can you make that an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B: I am not keen on getting the "unsung hero badge" ;-)

Answer (score 7):

As has been pointed out in the comments, you need to redefine the typeset counter, which is done by `\appendix` using alphabetical numeration by default. If the class in use does not provide chapters, the sections are the highest level and their typeset counter has to be redefined.

Since roman numerals get out of line pretty quick, i used package `tocstyle` that takes care of this. You need some compilations to finish the itereation though.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[tocgraduated]{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{duck}
\chapter{goose}
\chapter{hen}
\chapter{hen}
\appendix
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
%\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}%If there are no chapters
\chapter{duckling}
\chapter{gosling}
\chapter{chick}
\chapter{poult}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't indicated which document class you're using, so I'll assume it's one of the "standard" classes -- `article`, `report`, and `book`. If this assumption is correct, you can achieve your objective by inserting the following instructions in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\appendix}{\@Alph}{\@Roman}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: This did not work

Comment: @Tvde1 - A comment such as "This did not work" is, sadly, entirely unhelpful and unactionable. To help diagnose *why* the proposed solution doesn't work, you should at a very minimum indicate which document class you use.

Comment: I'm using `report` and pdfLaTex. Nothing changes when I run the code.

Answer (score 0):

try \CTEXsetup[number=\Roman{chapter}]{chapter} if the appendix consists of chapters

```
\appendix
\CTEXsetup[number=\Roman{chapter}]{chapter} 
\include{chap/encl1}
\include{chap/encl2}
\include{chap/encl3}
\include{chap/encl4}
\include{chap/encl5}
```

Comment: Please, do _not_ add code screenshots.